# What does どくしんでハンサムだからね mean?

Tags: copula, particle-から, coordination

I can't understand what どくしんで means (I know there is the のです here but I can't understand the verb before it).

Also, in the second part ハンサムだから, I studied that から is Place at the end of the first sentence with the second part of the sentence following it (...だから...), isn't it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> 独身{どくしん} で ハンサム だから ね

Without further context it's hard to tell who is the subject/object of this phrase, but it shall be read:

> It's because だから
>   *someone*
>   is single and... どくしんで
>   handsome ハンサム

Answer (score 2):

> [one or more factors that make one popular etc.]だからね

This is a common phrase to acknowledge someone for being pretty good in some way (popular, smart, etc.) either in front of them or when gossiping about them.

It's basically "It makes sense how he's popular with women when you know that he's single and handsome."

Japanese people fill in that sentence like this in their minds:

> 独身でハンサムだからそりゃモテるよね

- そりゃ slang for "of course," "naturally," "then"
- モテる "to be popular with the opposite sex"

In the sentence you wrote, it sounds like the speaker is talking to their friends about how some guy they know is popular.

Comment: When you say "...fill in that sentence like this in their minds," how accurate is the inference? Is it just from experience? I find myself always jumping to the wrong conclusion in these implied situations...

Comment: I was brought up in Japan and have heard of many instances like this. And for this particular phrase, I think if the speaker wanted to avoid to be taken this way, they would omit the ね at the end at least. I might be mistaken for this particular example in the question, but I'm confident that the example sentence alone would give many Japanese people this kind of impression.  

And this kind of phrase is something that instantly makes us want to read into the speaker's real intent, since we hear it often in gossips thus it sounds a bit hostile.

Answer (score 0):

"Cos you're single and handsome"